# Issue deploying with mina, cant migrate because db does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Im trying to deploy with Mina. I get stuck on database migrations because it say the database does not exist.

```
Your bundle is complete!
Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
It was installed into ./vendor/bundle
-----> Migrating database
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError: FATAL:  database "production" does not exist
Run `$ bin/rake db:create db:migrate` to create your database
```

How can I create the database using mina or ssh? im using ubuntu 14.04 on digitalocean

Comment: See https://gist.github.com/jbonney/6257372#file-deploy-rb-L143-L165 for an example of creating database by running the sql query with mina.

Comment: That appears to be for mysql how would I do the same in postgres?

Comment: Should be similar. See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-createdatabase.html for the exact syntax.